# Wordcloud showing colour based on a variable in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, word-cloud

I'm creating a wordcloud in which the size of the words is based on frequency, but i want the colour of the words to be defined by a variable (a string). The aim is to join two types of a dataset in one wordcloud and to differentiate by color.  For example, if the type is 'Job' the word appear with the colour blue (#297FD5) and if it's 'Tal' appear with the color grey (#595959).

I tried the following, which gave me the colour defined by the code and not what i want.

```
AllWords <- data.frame(word = c("Database", "Database", "Javascript","Javascript", "Java", "Java", "CSS", "CSS"), 
                       scale = c(1.007728, 1.111018, 11.892040, 14.085705, 8.031906, 11.009304, 5.026064, 9.257963 ), 
                       type = c("Job", "Tal","Job", "Tal","Job", "Tal","Job", "Tal"), 
                       df_color = c("#297FD5", "#595959","#297FD5", "#595959","#297FD5", "#595959","#297FD5", "#595959"))

#Packages
library(ggwordcloud)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, quietly = TRUE)
library(dplyr, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr, quietly = TRUE)

#Wordcloud
set.seed(42)
ggplot(
  AllWords, 
  aes(
    label = word, 
    size = scale,
    color = df_color
    )) +
  geom_text_wordcloud_area(rm_outside = TRUE, eccentricity = 1) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 10) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Does anyone know how i can change the color for the words depending from a string?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the color names or hex codes stored in your column `df_color` you have to use `scale_color_identity`:

```r
library(ggwordcloud)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)
ggplot(
  AllWords, 
  aes(
    label = word, 
    size = scale,
    color = df_color
  )) +
  geom_text_wordcloud_area(rm_outside = TRUE, eccentricity = 1) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 10) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It's works like you mention it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you are looking for. Since you are using the `aes` wrapper within `ggplot`, you need to color the group by changing `color` to what you want the color to be grouped by. Then you just add `scale_color_manual` with the colors you want:

```
#Wordcloud
set.seed(42)
ggplot(
  AllWords, 
  aes(
    label = word, 
    size = scale,
    color = word,
  )) +
  geom_text_wordcloud_area(
                           rm_outside = TRUE, 
                           eccentricity = 1) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 10) +
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#297FD5", "red", "#704238", "#A64C93"))
```

[image]